# Make a request to download a video in Python

Tags: python, http-post

I have links of the form:

```
http://youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?video=LINK_TO_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_HERE
```

If you put links of this type in an `<a>` tag on a webpage, clicking them will download an MP3 of the youtube video at the end of the link. Source is [here](http://youtubeinmp3.com/api/).

I'd like to mimic this process from the command-line by making post requests (or something of that sort), but I'm not sure how to do it in Python! Can I get any advice, please, or is this more difficult than I'm making it out to be?

Comment: There is a function in the standard library that does exactly this.

Comment: Awesome. What's the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Mark Ma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415143/mark-ma) mentioned, you can get it done without leaving the standard library by utilizing `urllib2`. I like to use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), so I cooked this up:

```
import os
import requests

dump_directory = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'mp3')
os.makedirs(dump_directory, exist_ok=True)


def dump_mp3_for(resource):
    payload = {
        'api': 'advanced',
        'format': 'JSON',
        'video': resource
    }
    initial_request = requests.get('http://youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/', params=payload)
    if initial_request.status_code == 200:  # good to go
        download_mp3_at(initial_request)


def download_mp3_at(initial_request):
    j = initial_request.json()
    filename = '{0}.mp3'.format(j['title'])
    r = requests.get(j['link'], stream=True)
    with open(os.path.join(dump_directory, filename), 'wb') as f:
        print('Dumping "{0}"...'.format(filename))
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
                f.flush()
```

It's then trivial to iterate over a list of YouTube video links and pass them into `dump_mp3_for()` one-by-one.

```
for video in ['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i62Zjga8JOM']:
    dump_mp3_for(video)
```

Comment: Your edit is incorrect. Python 2 also supports the `with` context manager.

Answer (score 1):

In its [API Doc](http://youtubeinmp3.com/api/), it provides one version of URL which returns download link as JSON: http://youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?api=advanced&format=JSON&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i62Zjga8JOM

Ok Then we can use urllib2 to call the API and fetch API result, then unserialize with json.loads(), and download mp3 file using urllib2 again.

```
import urllib2
import json

r = urllib2.urlopen('http://youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?api=advanced&format=JSON&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i62Zjga8JOM')
content = r.read()
# extract download link
download_url = json.loads(content)['link']
download_content = urllib2.urlopen(download_url).read()
# save downloaded content to file
f = open('test.mp3', 'wb')
f.write(download_content)
f.close()
```

Notice the file should be opened using mode 'wb', otherwise the mp3 file cannot be played correctly.
If the file is big, downloading will be a time-consuming progress. And here is a post describes how to [display downloading progress in GUI (PySide)](http://redino.net/blog/2013/07/pyside-downloading-file-with-progress-bar/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download video or just the audio from YouTube you can use this module [pytube](https://github.com/nficano/pytube) it does all the hard work.

You can also list the audio only:

```
from pytube import YouTube

# initialize a YouTube object by the url
yt = YouTube("YOUTUBE_URL")

# that will get all audio files available
audio_list = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).all()
print(audio_list)
```

And then download it:

```
# that will download the file to current working directory
yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True)[0].download()
```

Complete Code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube ("YOUTUBE_URL")
audio = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
audio.download()
```